# Using ewa namespace with MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've found a namespace called Ewa: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee589018(v=office.15).aspx

I'm quite new to all this (as you will see) but I would like to use this library/namespace. After some reading it looks like it can be used like an excel spreadsheet and that's exactly what I want, but I have no idea how I reference or import these functions.

I'm using MVC right now and wonder if this is something I should connect through via my Controller or with JS/Jquery?

Been looking around and found something about SharePoint but is that really necessary just to use EWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ewa namespace applies to the Excel Web Access part from Sharepoint excel services.  Its a javascript library available client side in Sharepoint when using ExcelServices to embed spreadsheets in a Sharepoint document.  Ewa doesnt exist outside of Sharepoint.